# IF Statement with OR operator not working

Tags: php

What I thought was to be a simple `IF` statement with a `||` operator isn't working. Am I just overlooking something in this code?

It works if I remove the `||` operator and test each condition separately. But not the way I have it shown below

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Projects` WHERE `EmpID` = '$eID'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row["ProjectStatus"] != 'Cancelled' || $row["ProjectStatus"] != 'Complete') {
            $imgnum = rand(0, 100);
            echo '
                <a href="index.php?proj=' . $row["ProjectSubDomain"] . '&ProID=' . $row["ProjectID"] . '">
                <div class="card mb-10" style="width:350px">
                    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/275/100/?image=' . $imgnum . '" alt="Card image">
                    <div class="card-img-overlay text-w-glow">
                        <h3 class="card-title">' . $row["ProjectName"] . '</h3>
                        <p class="card-text">' . $row["ProjectType"] . '</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        Project Status: ' . $row["ProjectStatus"] . '
                    </div>
                </div>
                </a>
                <br>
            ';
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "No Current Projects";
}
```

Can anyone assist when my oversight is and point me back in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: Because you want AND `&&`.

Comment: Compare `ProjectStatus IS NOT Cancelled OR ProjectStatus IS NOT Complete` vs `ProjectStatus IS NOT Cancelled AND ProjectStatus IS NOT Complete`. The first means that only 1 clause has to pass, so if ProjecStatus is Complete will pass the `ProjectStatus IS NOT Cancelled` clause. Whereas using `&&`, both clauses will have to pass in order for it to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `||` it won't work because if the status is "Complete" it's different from "Cancelled" and vice-versa, so you are telling it to discard "Complete" and "Cancelled" as well. You must use `&&`instead.

```
if ($row["ProjectStatus"] != 'Cancelled' && $row["ProjectStatus"] != 'Complete') {
```

Answer (score 1):

Complete or cancelled matches the opposite. I would do:

```
if(!in_array($row["ProjectStatus"],  array('Cancelled', 'Complete'))) {
```